# jQuery filter methods in array of objects which are contents of an object

Tags: jquery

os.networkInterfaces() is a function used in node-webkit applications to get network related data of client machine.
For my machine it is like
[image]

I write a code to get IPv4 address of the client machine to use in my nw.js app. The logic is; find *address* from the object where *internal* is *false* and *family* is *IPv4*. this is the code.

```
$.each(os.networkInterfaces(),function(key,value){
    $(value).each(function(index,item){
        if(item.internal==false && item.family=='IPv4'){
            console.log(item.address); // result is "10.0.8.42" from the above picture
        }
    });
});
```

Is there any other way to achieve this. Can we apply jquery filter methods here in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Dont use jQuery - just use regular vanilla JS Array.reduce and Array.filter:

```
let interfaces = os.networkInterfaces()
let matchingObjects = Object.keys(interfaces).reduce(function(matches, key) {
    return matches.concat(interfaces[key].filter(function(face) {
        return face.internal === false && face.family === "IPv4"
    }).map(function(face) {
        return face.address; //just get the address
    }));
}, []);
```